# Would the Prefects' Bathroom somehow lock when someone was bathing in it?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Or could people just enter anytime, even if someone was in there already?

Comment: The Prefects bathroom was always locked. That's why Harry needed a password.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. If he went inside and started bathing and someone else came to the door and said the password, would they be able to get in even though Harry was in there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes. It had a bolt.

> When he reached the statue of Boris the Bewildered, a lost-looking wizard with his gloves on the wrong hands, he located the right door, leaned close to it, and muttered the password, "Pine fresh," just as Cedric had told him.
>   The door creaked open. Harry slipped inside, **bolted the door** behind him, and pulled off the Invisibility Cloak, looking around.
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 25, The Egg and the Eye)*.</sub>

Comment: Good catch. I was expecting the answer to be: "it's not explicitly stated, but it does stand to reason" so I didn't bother checking. Good answer